# lapply over a list using it as input

Tags: r, lapply

I've got a list of things:

```
thing_list <- list("thing1","thing2","thing3")
```

And a function that takes one thing, and produces a result

```
function(thing){
    do operations with the thing
    return(result)
}
```

I want to apply the function to each element in the list. And store the result in a different list.

Here is where I have the doubt:

```
restul_list <- lapply(things_list, function(**HOW TO REFERENCE THE CURRENT THING AS ARGUMENT**))
```

How can I pass each element in the list as lapply goes by, as an argument for the function.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If we want to `get` the value (`data.frame` or `vector` or `matrix`, etc) stored in the objects, use `mget` to return a `list` of object values and then loop with `lapply`

```
 thing_list <-  c("thing1","thing2","thing3")
 lapply(mget(thing_list), yourfun)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
lapply(thing_list, f)
```

Where `f` is your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
result_list <- lapply(things_list, function(x) thing(x))
```